# How should I infer the C data type of an addb instruction on a x86-64 machine?

Tags: c, assembly, types, x86-64

I have the following C code where both v and b are signed data type or pointers to a signed data type. We also know that sizeof(b) = 2.

```
*v+=b
```

The assembly code on x86-64 is...

```
addb %sil, (%rcx)
```

The question is what is the C data type for v and b?

I understand that %sil corresponds to b and %rcx corresponds to v. 
However, the solution says "because the lower-order byte of b is added to the byte pointed to by %rcx, v must be of type char*. "

I do not understand why v must be a char*. Why cannot it be a short*?

Note: it could that it is a misprint since there is another misprint on this question posted on the errata of the book already.

Comment: The `b` in `addb` means byte, 8 bits. also `sil` is a 8 bit register. As such, it must be a 8 bit value and that is (probably) `char` not `short`. It can not be `short` (assuming that is 16 bit) because the addition wouldn't handle carry from low 8 bits to high 8 bits properly. Oh, `We also know that sizeof(b) = 2`??? Are you sure? If there is a misprint, it's that. `sizeof(b)` should be `1`.

Comment: I am not entirely sure why, but I just checked the book and b is two bytes used in the book. It is probably platform-dependent? For this question, we should assume that addb adds two bytes as it is the assumption used in the book.

Comment: Although you could add a `short` to a `char` (with truncation) so that might even be considered correct, if misleading.

Comment: As the solution says, it is because some value is "*added to the byte pointed to by %rcx*". A `short` isn't just a single byte.

Comment: @melpomene I could be wrong, but i thought (%rcx) would take two bytes from the location referenced by %rcx (because it is used by a addb)?

Comment: `b` is byte. *One* byte. Also `sil` is 1 byte. But I have told you that already.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the title of the book? Also, the easiest way to understand what is going on to write a simple example in C and compile it for x86_64. You can analyze the disassembly using a tool such as objdump, or simply give gcc the -S flag to only produce assembly.

Comment: Your question is about inferring data types from assembly. You generally don't have source code when analyzing assembly code, so context is the best way to infer types. Good indicators could be if the type is passed to a well defined function, or how operations performed on the data. From this example addb would make me infer you are dealing with a single-byte type, such as a char. Sometimes it makes sense to add to pointers but only if data is later dereferenced such as an array access or virtual table lookup. Also pointers must be the size of an address so contextually this is likely a char.

Comment: @Jester  You are right. It is a byte. It is my bad that I was thinking of b in my mind, but I was checking it against w. Your comment answers the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not understand why v must be a char*. Why cannot it be a short*?

It can't be `short*` because `addb` is byte operand-size, and `%sil` is an 8-bit register.  `short` is a 16-bit type in C ABIs for x86-64.  (ISO C requires `short` to be at least 16 bits.)

The operand-size for `add` determines how many bytes in memory are modified, i.e. the size of the object-representation of `*v`.

If `*v` had been `short`, it would have been an error to discard carry-out from the low byte, instead of letting it propagate into the high byte, even if for some reason we knew `b`'s value was small.

---

`sizeof(b) = 2` is a trick / red herring:

In C rules, types narrower than `int` as operands to operators like `+=` are promoted to `int`, and then the `int` addition result is converted back down to the destination type.

**So `*v += b` doesn't care if `b` is wider or narrower than `*v`.**  That's why the question had to tell you `sizeof(b)`; because you *can't* infer that from the `addb` instruction and it doesn't have to match the type of `*v`.

In both x86-64 System V and Windows x64, the only 16-bit integer types are `short` and `unsigned short`, so `sizeof(b) == 2` tells us that `b` is `short` or `unsigned short`.

(Those ABIs also have CHAR_BIT = 8 i.e. 1-byte `char`, which is normal for machines with byte-addressable memory.)

---

The fixed-width types like `uint8_t` and `int16_t` are typedefs for `unsigned char` and `short`, and so on.  I'm not counting them for this.

The question also lets us rule out unsigned types, which we couldn't from the asm.  Unsigned addition and 2's complement addition are the same binary operation.

Comment: We have also been told that _"both v and b are signed data type or pointers to a signed data type."_ But in general, yeah, unsigned would look the same.